# Complement on pre-sorted lists

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, sorting

Is there any way to instruct `Complement` to skip the sorting part? If the answer is no (likely), the next question would be: **how can I remove from a sorted list another sorted list** (in an efficient way)?

I would like the output of the following code to be `{1,3}` as in the usual `Complement` function:

```
universe = {1, 2, 3};
subst = {2} ;
myComplement[universe, subst]
```

But the output of the following code should be `{3, 2, 1}` because it stopped trying to remove terms after it realized that`subst[[1]] > universe[[1]]`.

```
universe = {3, 2, 1};
subst = {2};
myComplement[universe, subst]
```

This question is different from a simple use of `Complement` or `DeleteCases` because we must use the fact that the lists are (assumed) sorted for efficiency. In the example below, the list `universe` has $2^{25}-1$ elements.

---

### The motivation for this question.

While answering [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30051/8803), I tried to go from listing the classes of equivalence of 4x4 matrices (as requested by the original question) to 5x5 case (just to push it). My answer solved the 4x4 case in 4 seconds. But the same algorithm, I estimated, will take 3 hours for the 5x5 case.

```
toMatrix = Partition[IntegerDigits[#, 2, 25], 5] &;
toInteger = FromDigits[Flatten[#], 2] &;
allSyms = 
  Module[{s1, s3, s4, s6}, {#, s1 = Reverse[#, {2}], Reverse[#], 
      s3 = Transpose[#], s4 = Reverse[s3, {2}], 
     Reverse[Transpose[s1], {2}], s6 = Reverse[Transpose[s4], {2}], 
     Reverse[Transpose[s6], {2}]}] &;
casesToCheck = Range[0, 2^25 - 1];
Timing[answer = {MatrixForm@toMatrix@First[#], 
     Length[#]} & /@ (Reap[
      NestWhile[
       Complement[#, 
         Sow[Union[toInteger /@ allSyms[toMatrix[#[[1]]]]]]] &, 
       casesToCheck, (n = Length[#]) > 0 &]][[2, 1]]); Length[answer]]
```

Obviously, there is a major bottleneck that is triggered now. I guess it is because `Complement` sorts the input. Instead of sorting a list of 65536 integers, the 5x5 case deals with a list of 33554432 integers.

Comment: Can you simplify your question somewhat and supply some simple test cases and desired results?

Comment: Related / possible duplicate (see answers for unsorted complement): http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1290/131. In short, `DeleteCases[universe, Alternatives @@ subst]` should do what you want (no clue about performance).

Comment: @Yves I am not voting to close.  This is *closely* related, but different.  A complement should not include duplicate elements, yet e.g. `DeleteCases[{3, 5, 7, 1, 4, 5}, 3 | 2 | 7]` does.  On the other hand there is a faster method for a true complement which I have posted in an answer.

Comment: Wait a minute; I just read "*But the output of the following code should be {3,2,1} because it stopped trying to remove terms after it realized thatsubst[[1]]>universe[[1]].*" again; this I don't understand.  This does not sound like a complement at all.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard not regarding the conflicting question title and content you are correct - there would be need for another `DeleteDuplicates`.

Comment: @Yves at least in v7 my `orderedComplement` is much faster than `oc2[all_List, i__List] := DeleteCases[DeleteDuplicates @ all, Alternatives @@ Union[i]]` -- can you confirm in a later version?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard depending on the number of elements your version is about two times faster (1000 elements) and drawing equal at 10^7 elements...

Comment: @YvesKlett Boy, they sure did improve the speed of that in later versions.  It's orders of magnitude different in v7.

Comment: There were issues in 7 with DeleteDuplicates as well (e.g. vs. Tally) which obviously were fixed in the meantime.

Comment: Hector, would you mind commenting on @Mr.Wizard´s question, specifically: should the output for `{3,2,1}` and `{2}` be `{3,1}` or `{3,2,1}` (which does not really make sense) and edit the question accordingly?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard "the output of ..." refers to the fact that you can assume that the input lists have already been sorted. I'll edit the question to make this more specific.

Comment: @Hector Regarding your update, since applying `Sort` to an already sorted list is quite fast (your 2^25 example takes under 1.5 second here) I doubt you're going to be able to beat `Complement` by much.  If both lists are sorted *and* internally free of duplicates this code may be a little faster than `Complement`: `DeleteDuplicates[Join@##] ~Drop~ Length[#] &[subst, universe]`.  Do you have reason to believe a faster method is even possible?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Let me do some timings. As for a reason to believe that there is a faster method, I think that if we remove the redundant part from an algorithm it will run faster. The problem is that Mathematica does not have the tools to remove the redundant part from `Complement`.

Comment: @Hector I disagree.  First, I don't think it is redundant; I believe that the complement operation is done *during* the sort.  Second, my proposed method (in the above comment) does not do any sorting and it's pretty much the same speed (on presorted lists) as `Complement`.  I'm afraid you're seeking the impossible here, but I'm always happy to be proven wrong if I can learn from it.

Comment: Thanks for the Accept.  I'm sorry I don't have anything more satisfying for you.  I included my simplified version in my answer and preserved the original for anyone who comes upon this question and has the *other* meaning in mind.

Comment: `Complement` constructs a new list each time it is invoked. This makes your algorithm's running time quadratic in the size of `casesToCheck`, even if `Complement` runs in constant time. Since your goal is to pull out equivalence classes, it would be better to traverse `casesToCheck` once, sowing each element which is the first element in its (presorted) equivalence class. This is a linear-

Comment: -(oops)- time algorithm since the equivalence classes have a constant bound on their size.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Revised answer

For the true meaning of the question as it has now been clarified:

I do not believe you are likely to be able to greatly improve over `Complement` as I believe the sort is not superfluous but rather an integral part of the algorithm.  I can only offer my `orderedComplement` without the pre-processing; it may in some cases be faster as it uses a different algorithm that does not sort:

```
presortedComplement[all_List, i_List] :=
  DeleteDuplicates[Join[i, all]] ~Drop~ Length[i]
```

This assumes an input of (only) two sorted lists of unique elements as would be output by `Union`.

---

**Original answer**

I propose:

```
orderedComplement[all_List, i__List] := 
  DeleteDuplicates[Join @ ##] ~Drop~ Length[#] &[Union @ i, DeleteDuplicates @ all]

orderedComplement[{3, 5, 7, 1, 4, 5}, {3, 2}, {7}]
```

> ```
> {5, 1, 4}
> ```

---

As [Leonid described](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1291/121), in version 8 `DeleteCases` has been optimized in such a fashion that it may have acceptable speed, and it is conceptually simpler; in version 7 it is *orders of magnitude* slower:

```
ocV8[all_List, i__List] := DeleteCases[DeleteDuplicates @ all, Alternatives @@ Union[i]]
```

Answer (score 3):

This may be faster than using `Alternatives`:-

```
universe = {3, 2, 4, 2, 7, 1};
subst = {2, 7, 8};

myComplement[universe_, subst_] := Module[{test},
  Scan[(test@# = True) &, subst];
  DeleteCases[universe, _?test]]

myComplement[universe, subst]
```

> {3, 4, 1}

This solution is based on answers from here: [Quick multiple selections from a list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19223/363)

**Timings**

*On version 7*

```
universe = RandomInteger[1000000, 100000];
subst = RandomInteger[20000, 20000];

myComplement[universe_, subst_] := Module[{test},
   Scan[(test@# = True) &, Union@subst];
   DeleteCases[DeleteDuplicates@universe, _?test]];

orderedComplement[all_List, i__List] := 
  DeleteDuplicates[Join@##]~Drop~Length[#] &[Union@i, 
   DeleteDuplicates@all];

ocV7[all_List, i__List] := 
  DeleteCases[DeleteDuplicates@all, Alternatives @@ Union[i]];

Print[First@Timing@myComplement[universe, subst], " seconds"];
Print[First@Timing@orderedComplement[universe, subst], " seconds"];
Print[First@Timing@ocV7[universe, subst], " seconds"];
```

> 0.125 seconds
>
> 0.0 seconds
>
> 19.765 seconds

*On version 9*

```
universe = RandomInteger[1000000, 100000];
subst = RandomInteger[20000, 20000];

myComplement[universe_, subst_] := Module[{test},
   Scan[(test@# = True) &, Union@subst];
   DeleteCases[DeleteDuplicates@universe, _?test]];

ocV9[all_List, i__List] := 
  DeleteCases[DeleteDuplicates@all, Alternatives @@ Union[i]];

Print[First@Timing@myComplement[universe, subst], " seconds"];
Print[First@Timing@orderedComplement[universe, subst], " seconds"];
Print[First@Timing@ocV9[universe, subst], " seconds"];
```

> 0.140401 seconds
>
> 0.015600 seconds
>
> 0.031200 seconds

Comment: (1) The question has been altered to mean something rather different (from what I understood it to be).  (2) Have you actually timed this?

Comment: I've just done the timings... Interesting result for version 7 users.

Comment: Chris, I'm not trying to be an ass (but I'm probably succeeding...) but I'm not seeing the point of this answer.  Alternatives in v7 is horribly slow, yes.  As shown in v9 it's a lot better.  And in both versions I believe `orderedComplement` is fastest of all.  *More importantly* this doesn't answer the question in its present state; if it were not for that I'd give my vote because I like alternatives but as it is it doesn't improve upon my answer for the old question or answer the new one.  // Off[grumpy-pants] &

Comment: I initially thought your ocV8 was a simpler case of your `orderedComplement` solution.  I'll see if I can improve my answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The question has not changed: how can I remove from a sorted list another sorted list (in an efficient way). I added to emphasize the "sorted" assumptions but those requirements were always there. By the way, your answer is 6% faster than `Complement`. Also, thanks for all the effort. I try to give back by answering some questions on my own.

Comment: @Hector as I said "from what I understood it to be."  In the original wording I took *sorted* to mean *ordered* as that seemed the more likely meaning.

Comment: Have added `orderedComplement` timings. Ambivalent about deleting. Funnily enough "> 0. seconds" rendered as "1. seconds"! (Try it in edit mode and see!)

Comment: @ChrisDegnen I appreciate the effort. I'll take Mr. Wizard's as the answer, but I am upvoting yours too.

Comment: Chris, I'm giving a +1 for the comparative timings that I was unable to provide myself.