# Generating the set of all three-dimensional binary arrays distinct under rotation and reflection?

Tags: list-manipulation

How can I automatically generate all possible three-dimensional binary arrays of size $(x_1 \times x_2 \times x_3$) where each array is distinct from all others with respect to rotation and reflection operations around any axis?  Is there a straightforward way to do this in Mathematica v9.0?

For three-dimensional arrays, rather than using nested lists, perhaps it would be better to use the form: `{{data1, {x1,y1,z1}},{data2, {x2,y2,z2}},{data3, {x3,y3,z3}},...}`.  So an example of the set of all three-dimensional array of dimensions $(x_1 \times x_2 \times x_3)$, where $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = 2$ would be:

```
coordinateArray = Tuples[{0, 1}, 3];
bitArray = Tuples[{0, 1}, 8];

arrayList = Array[{} &, Length[bitArray]];

For[i = 1, i <= Length[bitArray], i++,
  arrayList[[i]] = Partition[Riffle[bitArray[[i]], coordinateArray], 2];
];
```

The set of all such three-dimensional arrays of dimensions $(x_1 \times x_2 \times x_3)$, where $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = 2$ is given by `arrayList` of length (here) $2^8 = 256$:

```
arrayList
```

> ```
> {{{0, {0, 0, 0}}, {0, {0, 0, 1}}, {0, {0, 1, 0}}, {0, {0, 1, 1}}, {0, {1, 0, 0}}, 
>   {0, {1, 0, 1}}, {0, {1, 1, 0}}, {0, {1, 1, 1}}}, 
>  {{0, {0, 0, 0}}, {0, {0, 0, 1}}, {0, {0, 1, 0}}, {0, {0, 1, 1}}, {0, {1, 0, 0}}, 
>   {0, {1, 0, 1}}, {0, {1, 1, 0}}, {1, {1, 1, 1}}}, 
>  ..., 
>  {{1, {0, 0, 0}}, {1, {0, 0, 1}}, {1, {0, 1, 0}}, {1, {0, 1, 1}}, {1, {1, 0, 0}}, 
>   {1, {1, 0, 1}}, {1, {1, 1, 0}}, {1, {1, 1, 1}}}}
> ```

Comment: @rasher Well, starting in one-dimension, nothing more intelligent than using `Tuples` to generate a set of all possible arrays, then going through and pruning for reflection.  I need the set of all possible such arrays, so its a bit difficult to find a generating function for a code family that does the trick.

Comment: @rasher I was hoping for some tools to help with quickly pruning (down to $1$) codes / arrays that can be reflected or rotated on one-another.

Comment: Please post an example of a _three-dimensional binary array of size (x1 × x2 × x3)_

Comment: @belisarius Does my example make sense to you?

Comment: @belisarius The trouble I'm having is finding a fast way to throw out redundant arrays / codes that are rotationally or reflectionally symmetric to other arrays / codes.

Comment: No, sorry. But perhaps it's me.

Comment: @belisarius My question, my fault.  Hold on...

Comment: @belisarius A way to think about the x1 = x2 = x3 = 2 case is to imagine assigning a binary bit to each vertex of a cube (my `coordinateArray` is the set of coordinates for the cube vertices), and generating all such cubes.  My example above does this.

Comment: Closely related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29915/12